# Some tag synonyms to create

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I apparently don't have enough "tag score" to even suggest these so let me suggest them manually here on meta:

- The existing [male-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-speech) tag needs the newer tag [masculine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masculine-speech) made a synonym
- The existing [female-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-speech) tag needs the newer tag [feminine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminine-speech) made a synonym

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the current situation.

Currently, [male-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-speech) is a synonym for [masculine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masculine-speech), but there are two questions with [male-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-speech) which are not converted to [masculine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masculine-speech).  Similarly, [female-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-speech) is a synonym for [feminine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminine-speech), but there are five questions with [female-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-speech).

If we go with [masculine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masculine-speech) and [feminine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminine-speech), then the older tags should be merged to the newer tags.  If not, then the synonyms should not have been created.  Currently I do not have a particular opinion which is better.

For the record, here is a complete list of questions with each of these tags as of writing.

[male-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-speech)

- [What differences should I look out for between male vs female speech?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-differences-should-i-look-out-for-between-male-vs-female-pronunciation)
- [What is this crazy guy shouting?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/what-is-this-crazy-guy-shouting)

[female-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-speech)

- [Commonness of casual phrases like "あたし" and "ちっちゃい"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3/commonness-of-casual-phrases-like-atashi-and-chicchai)
- [What differences should I look out for between male vs female speech?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-differences-should-i-look-out-for-between-male-vs-female-pronunciation)
- [わ usage at the end of sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/244/wa-usage-at-the-end-of-sentences)
- [What exactly is "なの" (nano)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/what-exactly-is-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae-nano)
- [When women use わ at the end of a sentence, is it different from よ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/when-women-use-%e3%82%8f-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-is-it-different-from-%e3%82%88)

[masculine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masculine-speech)

- [What is the implication when a gruff old man ends a sentence with わ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/what-is-the-implication-when-a-gruff-old-man-ends-a-sentence-with-%e3%82%8f)

[feminine-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminine-speech)

- [What is the implication when a gruff old man ends a sentence with わ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/what-is-the-implication-when-a-gruff-old-man-ends-a-sentence-with-%e3%82%8f)

Comment: I'm not sure about this (was unable to find any official word), but creating a synonym may not automatically retag existing uses of the synonym.  It would only prevent new questions from using it.  The mods would be able to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better solution is to make all of them synonyms of a new tag with a wider scope like an umbrella term. After all some of the questions mention or compare both types of speech.

Maybe:

- [gender-specific-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-specific-speech)
- [male-vs-female-speech](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-vs-female-speech)

I'm sure somebody can come up with a better variant too.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure they're synonyms…
Can't you have some male feminine speach?

masculine/feminine sound to me as subjective, unlike male/female.

Comment: Well if you really really think all four tags makes for the most professional Stack Exchange site you're a lot more active around here than me. Is that how the tags are used though?

Comment: I don't really know… I tend to just ignore all tags and just look at question titles…